# Configuration File For .net(Unable to pass in correct values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, configuration-files

An exert from my config file looks liek this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="loglocal" value="C:\here.txt" />
    <add key="ConnString" value="Data Source=DBNAME;InitialCatalog=CataName;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add key="UppBound" value="100" />
    <add key="LowBound" value="100" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration
```

I am attempting to pass in some values into my .net program, and the only one that works is the `loglocal` which is picking a directory string.

I can pass in my bounds into queries but I cannot pass in the Connection string and open the connection.

I have tried passing in my own set of quotes as well before passing in the long query like:

```
Dim SQLCONN as new SqlConnection("""" & nameofconfvalue & """")
```

For reference my entire code looks like this.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim ConfUpperBound as Integer = Configuration.AppSettings("UppBound")
Dim ConfConnString as String = Configuration.AppSettings("ConnString")

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender as System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim SQLCONN as new SqlConnection("<either from config(fails) or hardcoded(works)>")

//fails on the below line (cannot open Connection)
SQLCONN.Open()

//I can successfully pass in values in query so I know i can connect to conf file
Dim SQLCMD as New SqlCommand("myquery etc etc")    
SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

SQLCONN.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT:** I am able to pass in the string perfectly when using Visual Studio 2005. But when using VS 2003 and a loiwer .net framework it will not let me, unless I hard code it in.

Could something be enabled/disabled on one of these instances of VS? Or could this just be an error with the older versions of .net? I think I am using 1.1??(will have to check) in 2003.

Comment: What about the typo for "Data Source" in your connection string: <... Data Spurce .../>

Comment: Just a typo on here, theres no typos in the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of .net are you using? If you're using 3.5 or above don't put it in the `appSettings` area, but instead put it in the `connectionStrings` section.

To read the connection string into your code, use the `ConfigurationSettings` class like this:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FooBar").ConnectionString)
```

Comment: I am using 2.0 but will try and mess around with the ConfigurationManager properties.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` method returns a `String`. Thus you have two options:

1) declare your variable as String:

```
Dim ConfUpperBound as String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UppBound")
```

2) Convert string value to an integer:

```
Dim ConfUpperBound as Int = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UppBound"))
```